# How can I update div content after JavaScript object change?

Tags: javascript, dom, state, rendering, reactive-programming

I'm writing a web app in which some contents are saved in a JavaScript object. The properties of the object can change at runtime, and I need to update the content of the element which display that property.

```html
change data name:
<input id="text">

<button id="btn">change</button>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>
  const search = document.getElementById('text');
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  const div = document.getElementById('content');

  const data = {
    id: '1',
    name: 'element name',
    inStock: true
  }

  div.innerHTML = `
        <div>id of the data: ${data.id}</div>
        <div>name of the data: ${data.name}</div>
        <div>is in stock: ${data.inStock}</div>
    `

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(data.name);
    data.name = search.value;
    console.log(data.name);
  })
</script>
```

After clicking the button, I change the property of the object `data`, and I would like to update the content of the `div`, and get something like

```
id of the data: 1
name of the data: new element name
is in stock: true
```

By locking at the console I see that indeed the property of the object changes, but not the `div` content.

I tried to solve this issue by replacing the child element

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.className = 'name';
    newDiv.innerHTML = `<div class="name">name of the data: ${data.name}</div>`;
    div.replaceChild(newDiv, document.getElementsByClassName('name')[0]);
})
```

and it works as expected, but I was wondering if it could be done in a more elegant way.

I hope I made myself clear enough, otherwise please ask more in the comments and I will update the question :)

Comment: There's nothing that links the div and the object, changing the object won't automatically update the div.

Comment: You could create a span for each object property and store references to those and update their `textContent` on click. But as @Barmar said, there is no reactive link between the object and the HTML

Comment: Yes it's not unexpected that without that "replaceChild" solution it wont work. How can i link the element to the object?

Comment: @PeterSeliger I rewrote the project using svelte and all the bindings between elements and data are automatically done

Comment: @john ... good choices, both continuing with the project and having picked svelte for it.

Answer (score 1):

The wide-spread **reactive approach**, used by most modern UI-frameworks, **does decouple the UI-event** (e.g. a control-value change or a form-submit) **and event-handler** based re/rendering of related DOM-content by ***exclusively* observing changes at just data-objects/models**. Such a model's ***state is the only truth***. Rendering of model-related UI-elements gets triggered exclusively by changes to such an observable object.

Observable data can be created by a proxy of e.g. a data-object of any initial state (the most basic being an empty object literal ... `{}`). One would use an [object's internal `[[Set]]` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy#object_internal_methods) via a [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) [`handler`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy#handler_functions)'s corresponding [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/Proxy/set) trap.

Any custom implementation of this `set`-specific callback-function has to at least try to cover all of the OP's possible needs in the most generic way.

One could achieve this by a kind of component-based solution which would initially rely on markup that features some specific [`data-*` global attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) and each of its [element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)-related [`dataset`-properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

Initializing a component should be done by passing its root-element to a function which takes care of e.g. ...

1. retrieving the component's initial state, which for instance could be provided by a [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)'ed custom attribute value like from `[data-initial-state]`.
2. creating an object based index/lookup of data-property related element-nodes, each being in need of a rerendering according to the changed data-entry.
3. creating an observable data-object from the initially provided state and from a data-change specific render-function where the latter binds all possible render-targets.
4. registering a handler-function which on form-data submit does handle just the most recent form-triggered data-changes in comparison to the observable data's current state ... again, any involved data-references are bound to this handler-function.
5. rendering all the data of the initially provided state where it belongs to ... like to any of the already retrieved target elements, and maybe even initially synchronizing any of the data-related form-controls according to the initially provided state.

Since an observable state is the pivotal point, one does apply any UI-triggered data-change (e.g. form submit) exclusively to the initially created observable data. The latter is a proxy of the initial state. The proxy's `set` method gets passed the mutated `object` as well as the affected property's/entry's `key` and `value`.

The 2nd crucial point is the rendering which has to update related data as soon as the observable state did change. That's the reason for introducing a proxy creating factory-function which expects both, the initial state and a custom render-function, where the render-function gets invoked with `key` and `value` via the observable state's `set` callback.

Thus, in order to always render just the related parts of affected data, the custom handler-function gets implemented as method which is aware of a `this` context where `this` refers a render-relevant index/lookup that needs to be bound to the custom handler.

```js
function renderDataTargetsInitially(elmForm, observableData, initialState) {
  console.log('initial rendering of ...');

  // - trigger the initial rendering of all of the initially provided
  //   data by assigning the latter to the observable data.
  Object.assign(observableData, initialState);

  // - synchronize any related form element value as well.
  // - do so by implementing just the least necessary functionality.
  Object
    .entries(initialState)
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {

      const namedItem = elmForm.elements[key];

      if (namedItem) {      
        const itemType = namedItem.constructor.name;

        if (itemType === 'RadioNodeList') {

          [...namedItem]
            .filter(control => control.value === String(value))
            .at(0)
            .checked = true;

        } else {
          namedItem.value = value;
        }
      }
    });
}

function handleMostRecentChangesAtBoundData(evt) {
  // - the custom handler-function which on submitting the form-data
  //   does take care of the submit-action and in addition does gather
  //   all the needed data for the generic data-change handler-function.
  evt.preventDefault();

  const { elmForm, observableData, recentData } = this;
  const formData = new FormData(elmForm);

  // - forward all data to a generically implemented handler-function
  //   which does exclusively handle the most recent data-changes in
  //   comparison to the observable data's current state.
  handleMostRecentDataChanges(
    observableData, recentData, Object.fromEntries(formData),
  );
}

function initializeReactiveDataComponent(componentRoot) {
  const elmForm = componentRoot
    .querySelector('form[data-initial-state]');

  // - retrieve the component's initial state.
  const initialState = JSON.parse(
    elmForm.dataset.initialState
  );
  // console.log({ initialState })

  // - needed just for initializing all of a component's states,
  // - obsolete from now.
  Reflect.deleteProperty(elmForm.dataset, 'initialState');

  // - create object based index/lookup of data-property related
  //   element-nodes, each being in need of a rerendering according
  //   to the changed data-entry (key-value pair of the observable data).
  const renderTargets =
    createAndInitializeRenderTargets(componentRoot, initialState);

  // - create an observable data object from the initially provided
  //   state and from a data-change specific render-function where
  //   the latter binds all possible render-targets.
  const observableData = createObservableData(
    initialState,
    renderDataChangeViaBoundTargetLookup.bind(renderTargets),
  );

  renderDataTargetsInitially(elmForm, observableData, initialState);

  // - register a handler-function which on form-data submit does
  //   handle just the most recent form-triggered data-changes in
  //   comparison to the observable data's current state ... again,
  //   any involved data-references are bound to this handler-function.
  elmForm.addEventListener(
    'submit', handleMostRecentChangesAtBoundData.bind({
      elmForm, observableData, recentData: structuredClone(initialState),
    }),
  );
}
initializeReactiveDataComponent(
  document.querySelector('#my-reactive-data-component')
);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
label { display: inline-block; margin: 0 2px 0 3px; }
label > span { display: block; }
fieldset { padding: 0 5px 2px 5px; }
fieldset, p { margin: 3px 0; }
.content { margin: 10px 0; }
section { width: 50%; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 49%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<section id="my-reactive-data-component">
  <!--
  <form data-initial-state='{"id":"1","name":"element name","inStock":true}'>
  -->
  <form data-initial-state="{&quot;id&quot;:&quot;1&quot;,&quot;name&quot;:&quot;element name&quot;,&quot;inStock&quot;:true}">
    <label>
      <span class="label">
        change <code>data.id</code>:
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="id" />
    </label>

    <label>
      <span class="label">
        change <code>data.name</code>:
      </span>
      <input type="text" name="name" />
    </label>

    <fieldset>
      <legend>is in stock</legend>
      <label>
        <span class="label">
          yes
        </span>
        <input type="radio" name="inStock" value="true" />
      </label>
      <label>
        <span class="label">
          no
        </span>
        <input type="radio" name="inStock" value="false" />
      </label>
    </fieldset>

    <button type="submit">change</button>
  </form>

  <article class="content">
    <p
      data-render-key="id"
      data-render-template="id in data: ${id}"
    >id in data: unknown</p>
    <p
      data-render-key="name"
      data-render-template="name in data: ${name}"
    >name in data: unknown</p>
    <p
      data-render-key="inStock"
      data-render-template="is in stock: ${inStock}"
    >is in stock: unknown</p>
  </article>
</section>

<script>
/*
 *  generically implemented functionality which can be re-used
 *  at every other project which follows the structural patterns
 *  (markup- and model-wise) of the proposed/described approach.
 */
function computeText(template, key, value) {
  return template.replace(
    RegExp(`\\$\\{\\s*${ key }\\s*\\}`, 'g'), value
  );
}

function createObservableData(data, handleDataChange) {
  // - create an observable data object from the initially provided
  //   data-value and a data-change specific callback.
  return new Proxy(data, {
    set: (obj, key, value) => {

      handleDataChange(key, value);

      return Reflect.set(...arguments);
    },
  });
}
function createAndInitializeRenderTargets(componentRoot, initialState) {
  // - create object based index/lookup of data-property related
  //   element-nodes, each being in need of a rerendering according
  //   to the changed data-entry (key-value pair of the observable data).
  return Object
    .keys(initialState)
    .reduce((targetLookup, key) => {

      const target = componentRoot
        .querySelector(`[data-render-key="${ key }"]`);

      if (target !== null) {
        targetLookup[key] = {
          target,
          template: target.dataset.renderTemplate ?? `$\{${key}\}`,
        }
      }
      // - needed just for initializing all of a component's states,
      // - obsolete from now.
      Reflect.deleteProperty(target.dataset, 'renderKey');
      Reflect.deleteProperty(target.dataset, 'renderTemplate');

      return targetLookup;
    }, {});
}

function renderDataChangeViaBoundTargetLookup(key, value) {
  const { target, template } = this[key];

  if (target && template) {
    target.textContent = computeText(template, key, value);
  }
  console.log({ key, value });
}

function handleMostRecentDataChanges(
  observableData, recentData, changedData
) {
  // - the handler-function which does exclusively handle
  //   the most recent data-changes in comparison to the
  //   observable data's current state.

  console.log('most recent changes ...');

  Object
    .entries(changedData)

    // - for each of the form data's key-value pair ...
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {

      // ... which has changed most recently ...
      if (recentData[key] !== value) {

        // ... - synchronice the recent data ...
        recentData[key] = value;
 
        // ... - and mutate the related
        //       observable data property.
        observableData[key] = value;
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

The <script/> tag within the markup part of the above provided example-code features all the generically implemented functionality which can be re-used at every other project which follows the structural patterns (markup- and model-wise) of the proposed/described approach.

Thus one just needs to provide additional problem specific functionality which one might trigger from the accordingly adapted/changed component initializing code.

The next provided example code proves the above statement with an implementation of [*Carsten Massmann's* example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77234210/2627243) which has been changed according to the here discussed reactive pattern.

```js
function keepFetchingAndUpdatingTemperaturesNorthOfHanover(
  observableData, recentData
) {
  const url =
    "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?longitude=9.7332&current_weather=true&latitude=";

  let { latitude } = observableData;
  --latitude;

  const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
    if (++latitude < 90) {

      fetch(url + latitude)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(meteoData => {
          const { current_weather: cw } = meteoData;

          handleMostRecentDataChanges(
            observableData, recentData, {
              latitude,
              cwTime: cw.time,
              cwTemperature: cw.temperature,
              fetchState: '... running ...',
            },
          );
        });
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalId);

      observableData.fetchState = 'finished.';
    }
  }, 1000);

  observableData.fetchState = '... initialized ...';
}

function initializeTemperaturesNorthOfHanover(componentRoot) {
  const initialState = {
    latitude: 51.3705,
    longitude: 9.7332,
    cwTime: 'still unknown',
    cwTemperature: 'still unknown',
    fetchState: 'not yet initialized',
  };
  // console.log({ initialState })

  // - create object based index/lookup of data-property related
  //   element-nodes, each being in need of a rerendering according
  //   to the changed data-entry (key-value pair of the observable data).
  const renderTargets =
    createAndInitializeRenderTargets(componentRoot, initialState);

  // - create an observable data object from the initially provided
  //   state and from a data-change specific render-function where
  //   the latter binds all possible render-targets.
  const observableData = createObservableData(
    initialState,
    renderDataChangeViaBoundTargetLookup.bind(renderTargets),
  );

  // - force rerendering of all initial state values by simply
  //   overwriting the observable data with the initial state.
  Object.assign(observableData, initialState);

  // - start with the actual task, the continouse data fetch/update.
  keepFetchingAndUpdatingTemperaturesNorthOfHanover(
    observableData, structuredClone(initialState)
  );
}
initializeTemperaturesNorthOfHanover(
  document.querySelector('#temperatures-north-of-hanover')
);
```

```css
body, h1, dl { margin: 0; }
h1 { font-size: .8em; }
dl { font-size: .85em; }
dd { font-family: monospace; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: 600; color: #666; }
.fetch-state { font-size: 1em; font-weight: 900; color: #000; }
section { width: 46%; }
.as-console-wrapper { left: auto!important; width: 55%; min-height: 100%; }
```

```html
<section id="temperatures-north-of-hanover">
  <h1>Current temperatures, north of Hanover, Germany</h1>
  <dl>
    <dt>latitude</dt>
    <dd data-render-key="latitude">unknown</dd>

    <dt>longitude</dt>
    <dd data-render-key="longitude">unknown</dd>

    <dt>time</dt>
    <dd data-render-key="cwTime">unknown</dd>

    <dt>temperature</dt>
    <dd
      data-render-key="cwTemperature"
      data-render-template="${cwTemperature}°C"
    >unknown</dd>

    <dt>fetch state</dt>
    <dd class="fetch-state" data-render-key="fetchState">unknown</dd>
  </dl>
</section>

<script>
/*
 *  generically implemented functionality which can be re-used
 *  at every other project which follows the structural patterns
 *  (markup- and model-wise) of the proposed/described approach.
 */
function computeText(template, key, value) {
  return template.replace(
    RegExp(`\\$\\{\\s*${ key }\\s*\\}`, 'g'), value
  );
}

function createObservableData(data, handleDataChange) {
  // - create an observable data object from the initially provided
  //   data-value and a data-change specific callback.
  return new Proxy(data, {
    set: (obj, key, value) => {

      handleDataChange(key, value);

      return Reflect.set(...arguments);
    },
  });
}
function createAndInitializeRenderTargets(componentRoot, initialState) {
  // - create object based index/lookup of data-property related
  //   element-nodes, each being in need of a rerendering according
  //   to the changed data-entry (key-value pair of the observable data).
  return Object
    .keys(initialState)
    .reduce((targetLookup, key) => {

      const target = componentRoot
        .querySelector(`[data-render-key="${ key }"]`);

      if (target !== null) {
        targetLookup[key] = {
          target,
          template: target.dataset.renderTemplate ?? `$\{${key}\}`,
        }
      }
      // - needed just for initializing all of a component's states,
      // - obsolete from now.
      Reflect.deleteProperty(target.dataset, 'renderKey');
      Reflect.deleteProperty(target.dataset, 'renderTemplate');

      return targetLookup;
    }, {});
}

function renderDataChangeViaBoundTargetLookup(key, value) {
  const { target, template } = this[key];

  if (target && template) {
    target.textContent = computeText(template, key, value);
  }
  console.log({ key, value });
}

function handleMostRecentDataChanges(
  observableData, recentData, changedData
) {
  // - the handler-function which does exclusively handle
  //   the most recent data-changes in comparison to the
  //   observable data's current state.

  console.log('most recent changes ...');

  Object
    .entries(changedData)

    // - for each of the form data's key-value pair ...
    .forEach(([key, value]) => {

      // ... which has changed most recently ...
      if (recentData[key] !== value) {

        // ... - synchronice the recent data ...
        recentData[key] = value;
 
        // ... - and mutate the related
        //       observable data property.
        observableData[key] = value;
      }
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a template, you can add the HTML to the page itself. And give each div an id and place an empty span in place of the content.

Then have a single function that takes the data as input and changes the HTML accordingly.

Then call that function on load and on click of the button.

```js
  const search = document.getElementById('text');
  const btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  const dataID = document.querySelector('#dataID span');
  const stock = document.querySelector('#stock span');
  const name = document.querySelector('#name span');
  const data = {
    id: '1',
    name: 'element name',
    inStock: true
  }
  
  function showData(data){
    stock.innerText = data.inStock;
    dataID.innerText = data.id;
    name.innerText = data.name;
  }

  showData(data);

  btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    data.name = search.value;
    showData(data);
  })
```

```html
change data name:
<input id="text">

<button id="btn">change</button>
<div id="content">
  <div id="dataID">id of the data: <span /></div>
  <div id="name">name of the data: <span /></div>
  <div id="stock">is in stock: <span /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Long story short you cant observe an object directly and have events for changes, react for example does it trough a setter function.
What you can do to be as clean as possible is to put all your html update code in a render function that receives an object, make a needUpdate function that compares the object value with the previous and if needed then call render, and use them to update the object or after doing that.

the render function you alleady have it, the trick might be in the needUpdate function, youu have 2 approach ways as I can see:

- If you need to track just shallow changes to object properties, you
  can iterate through object properties (using Object.entries) and set
  them values to another object (aka lastValues), then you can do the
  same but comparing currentValues[prop]===lastValues[prop] to know if
  something changed, this is shallow because if the object eventually
  have a property that is indeed an object with its own properties and
  you change one of these, you wont notice since the object property is
  still the same.
- If you need to track deep and more complex values (like a tree of
  objects), you colud use JSON.stringify to generate a string
  representation of all the hierarchy and compare it to the
  JSON.stringify(lastValues), this way looks a lot simpler and polish
  but at a cost os proccess that could outcome in hangs if you have a
  lot of changes and a big object

Done this you will have to:

1. apply the changes to the currentValues you have to
2. if(needUpdate(currentValues,lastValues)) render(currentValues)
3. Object.apply(lastValues,curentValues) //you need to have separated
   references on both objects.

Answer (score 0):

Below you will find a snippet that demonstrates how you can initially fill a div with data, using a template string and subsequently change the data in the created DOM element by changing the `.textContent` attributes of selected `<span>`s inside it:

```js
  const div = document.getElementById('content'),
      url = "https://api.open-meteo.com/v1/forecast?longitude=9.7332&current_weather=true&latitude=";
  let lat=51.3705, // Hanover, Germany
      data,        // global data object, with changing values
      spans;       // will hold a collection of spans to be updated

// get initial data for Hanover:
fetch(url+lat).then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>{ data=d;
  let cw=data.current_weather;
  div.innerHTML = `
        <div>latitude: <span>${data.latitude}</span></div>
        <div>longitude: ${data.longitude}</div>
        <div>time: <span>${cw.time}</span></div>
        <div>temperature: <span>${cw.temperature}</span>°C</div>`
  spans=div.querySelectorAll("span");
});

// move north in 1 degree steps and
// update the latitude, time and temperature spans:

const auto=setInterval(()=>{
  // display the current properties of the data object:
  let cw=data.current_weather, 
     arr=[data.latitude,cw.time,cw.temperature];
  spans.forEach(el=>el.textContent=arr.shift());
  // update the data object asynchronously ...
  // ... until we've reached the north pole:
  if (++lat<90) 
fetch(url+lat).then(r=>r.json()).then(d=>data=d);
  else clearInterval(auto);
},1000); // repeat in 2 second intervals ...
```

```html
Current temperatures, north of Hanover, Germany:
<div id="content"></div>
```

Everything can now be done with lightweight "Vanilla" JavaScript, without having to use frameworks like Angular, Vue or React.